# Filter list based on dropdown selection - SP 2013

Tags: list, filter

I would like to implement a list filter feature. I need to filter the list based on 3 drop down field values. The values of the drop down are populated from same list (that I want to filter).

I am thinking of implementing connected web parts with one web part having three drop down fields and other with list.

I have also looked at filtering list using URL parameters.

Kindly advise the best approach to implement the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the web part connection would be the best way to get this done through OOTB.

Since there are only 3 options, I would like to suggest one of these.

1. Add a list view webpart where the list is grouped by the field you wish to. It is much effective and the easiest.
2. Create 3 views and add some jquery tabbing where each tab will display items related to each view.

First one is easiest, but depending on the effeort you would like to put, 2nd one will be handy. End of the day its just 3 options.